# How to call a method in the object after auto-mapping in Angular HTTP?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the model `User`:

```
export class User {
   id: number;
   roles: Role[];

   hasRole(role: string) { return true; }
}
```

And in my user service, I use generics to map response to that model.

```
getById(id: number) {
   return this.http.get<User>(`/api/v1/admin/users/${id}`);
}
```

And then in the component, I'm trying to call `hasRole` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getById(1).subscribe(data => this.user = data);
}

checkRole() {
   return this.user.hasRole();
}
```

After I call `checkRole` I get the message:

**TypeError: this.user.hasRole is not a function**.

How do I can fix it?

Comment: How is `this.user` defined in you component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing in a type parameter to `get` you are not actually changing what `get` does internally, which is gets the data from the server and parses it into an object (using `JSON.parse` most likely). The reason to pass the parameter is to have typing for the object that will come from the server, but the object will not actually be an instance of the class, it will still be a simple object. To avoid this confusion you can use an interface that only contains the fields as the type parameter, and create the instance of `User` in `subscribe`

```
this.userService.getById(1).subscribe(data => this.user = Object.assign(new User(),  data));
```

Or a more typesafe way, that ensures nobody thinks the data returned from the `getById` is an actual instance of `User`:

```
type DataKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends Function ? never : P }[keyof T]
type Data<T> = Pick<T, DataKeys<T>>; 


getById(id: number) {
   return this.http.get<Data<User>>(`/api/v1/admin/users/${id}`);
}

this.userService.getById(1).subscribe(data => this.user = Object.assign(new User(),  data));
```

Comment: Tnx. What can I do with property `roles: Role[];`? Now I can call method `checkRole`, but actually, the `roles` property just objects, not instances of  `Role`.

Comment: You need to do the same for roles, create the Role using `new` and assign the data to the new object ..